# How to use Custom Directives in Angular 6 for Server Side Paging

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

I am using `Kendo Angular Grid ^3.6.0` with `Angular 6`.

I have found an article in Telerik site on how to create Custom Directive to achieve Server Side Paging.

You can see under Custom Directives section

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/automatic-operations/

My existing code contains a `user-grid.ts`, `user-grid.html` and `api.service.ts`. In this `user-grid.ts` file populates the front-end Telerik Kendo Grid with data like `Name`, `Address`, `Email` and `Mobile` columns

Currently, the grid fetches all the data for the first time and populates the grid pagewise. I want to change the implementation by changing it into Server Side paging.

```
public rebind(): void {
     this.apiService.GetUserDetails(this.loginUserId, this.state, this.totalRecords, this.searchedUserDetails).map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
         data: response['value'],
         total: parseInt(response['@odata.count'], 10)
     }));
}
```

Because I am not using `OData` here and fetching from `Oracle Database`, what are the keywords I have to use to retrieve for `data` and `total` for the grid to get populated instead of `value` and `@odata.count`. Where to specify and identify this keywords.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should I need to implement OData to achieve this?